# show or hide component with a trigger from multiplied combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't show or hide a component from a multiplied combo box, but I can show or hide it from an original combo box(the first combo box)
what should I do..?

this is function to multiply the combo box

```
function addEmploy() {}
    $('#addEmploy').click(function(){
        $('#comboEmploy')
        .append('<br />')
        .append($('#comboEmploy select').first().clone());
    });
```

this is script to show or hide the component

```
$("#employ").change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "2"){
            $("#comboStudy").show("slow");
        }else{
            $("#comboStudy").hide("slow");
        }
    });
```

This is the combo box

```
<span id="comboEmploy">
                <select name="employ[]" id="employ">
                    <option value="NULL" selected >Choose one</option>
                    <?php foreach ($employs as $employ) :?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $employ->employ_id; ?>">
                        <?php echo $employ->employ_name; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </span>
<a href="#" id="addEmploy">Add Employ</a>
```

This is the component that I want to show/hide

```
<span id="comboStudy">
            <select name="study[]" id="study">
                <option selected value=NULL>Choose one</option>
                <?php foreach ($studies as $study) :?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $study->study_id; ?>">
                        <?php echo $study->study_name; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            </span>
```

Can anyone help me. thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the `select` box, you need to tell jQuery to clone the events along with it:

```
.clone(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are appending elements to the DOM after page load you need to use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) function to attach their events:

```
$("#employ").live("change", function() {
    ...
}
```